# Whether all attempts to determine the ip address successfully if Master DNS shutdown and secondary DNS work

Tags: domain-name-system

Domain **exemple-domain.com** has two DNS server: ***dns1.exemple.com*** (master) and ***dns2.exemple.com*** (slave).

questions:
If dns1.exemple.com temporarily disabled and dns2.exemple.com works, is it possible that some attempts to define ip addresses fails?

I try it many times in succession

```
dig @8.8.8.8 exemple-domain.com | awk '/^;; ANSWER SECTION:$/ { getline ; print $5 }'
```

and part of the query does not receive a reply

Could there be a part of that traffic would be lost if dns1.exemple.com not working and dns2.exemple.com work?

Comment: I know your question is worded differently, but the linked Q&A answers this topic in detail.

Answer (score 0):

That depends.

If the first server simply isn't answering at all, resolvers *should* retry their queries against the other one. It is, of course, up to them if they actually *do* retry or not. And it's another question if the second name server will be able to answer. If it is a slave server and the master server has been gone for too long, all the data the slave had will have expired, so it cannot answer questions (it will still send a response, saying `SERVFAIL`, though).

So, yes, it *could* be as you think. As in, it's not impossible. But it *is* impossible for us to do more than guess wildly until you tell us which domain you're talking about.